# Route with /:id returns 404 for client side javascript

Tags: node.js, express

I am using numerous routes in express and node, and for the routes that use an "/:id" at the end of the route, it returns 404 not found for the client-side javascript files.

this route works

```
app.route('/createPoll')
   .get(function (req, res) {
    res.render(path + '/public/createPoll.ejs', {
        userID: "logged-in"
    });
};)
```

this route does not find the javascript file

```
app.route('/deletePoll/:id')
    .get(function (req, res) {
    res.render(path + '/public/profile.ejs', {
        userID: "logged-in"
    });
};
```

They are both looking for the same common javascript files located in app/common and app/controllers. How to correct the path for the route with /:id?

Comment: Depending on how are you handling the render files (setting `views` path in express for example), path might not be the route you want, what do you get if you log `path + '/public/profile.ejs'`?

Comment: I have the views set in public/. Path is set as process.cwd. I logged the the public profile and it goes to the same directory as the createPoll locally. `C:\<local path> Voting/public/profile.ejs`

Comment: In the file where you setup express, you should have a line with something like the following: `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/public'))`, if so, you can render simply with the code `res.render('profile.ejs'. { userID: 'logged-in' })`